# 3D metrics for segmentation evaluation

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, file, numpy

I am new to programming and I am trying to develop a machine learning approach for image segmentation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation) and here I want to evaluate the predicted (output) segmentation. In order to do this, I am using multiple (common) metrics (dice score, jacquard index, surface distance Hausdorff distance, diameter error and volume error).

The code works, but it really looks bad! I heard that one of the best practices is to avoid repetition in the code. For my piece I have to create multiple arrays which will all have different usage, but generating a lot of repetitions, and I am sure there might be better way to get better performance for this piece of code.

Do you have an idea of how to optimize this for speed and readability?

The details of the code:

`folder = glab()` : gets the name of the different folders containing the arrays that I want to open (`glab() = glob()` with natural sorting)

`prediction`/`ground_truth` : loads the predicted segmentation and ground_truth to be compared

`scores()` : calculates the different metrics (dice score, jacquard index, sensibility and specificity) between the ground truth and prediction

`surfd()` : calculates the surface distance between ground truth and prediction

`diam_vol` : calculates the diameter/volume and error between ground truth and prediction

Since I am evaluating multiple cases I want to know the `mean()` metrics to assess my model that's why I call for `np.mean()` for all the values at the end.

```
def metrics(savedir):

    """3D metrics for segmentation evaluation:

    dice score : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient
    jacquard index : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index
    sensibility & specificity : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity
    diameter and volume error
    Surface distance : https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/7732/CS-RR-15-08.pdf
    Hausdorff distance : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance
    """

    folder = glab(savedir+"/OutputData/*/")

    # array initialization
    np_dice = np.zeros([len(folder)])
    np_jacq = np.zeros([len(folder)])
    np_sens = np.zeros([len(folder)])
    np_spec = np.zeros([len(folder)])
    np_surf = np.zeros([len(folder)])
    np_haus = np.zeros([len(folder)])

    np_diam_GT = np.zeros([len(folder)])
    np_diam_pred = np.zeros([len(folder)])
    np_diam_err = np.zeros([len(folder)])

    np_vol_GT = np.zeros([len(folder)])
    np_vol_pred = np.zeros([len(folder)])
    np_vol_err = np.zeros([len(folder)])


    for number, folder_name in enumerate(folder):

        prediction = np.load(folder_name+"prediction.npy")
        ground_truth = np.load(folder_name+"test_label.npy")

        scores = scoring(ground_truth, prediction)
        surface_distance = surfd(prediction, ground_truth, [0.625, 0.625, 0.625], 1)
        diam_vol = diam(prediction, ground_truth)

        np_dice[number] = scores[0]
        np_jacq[number] = scores[1]
        np_sens[number] = scores[2]
        np_spec[number] = scores[3]
        np_surf[number] = surface_distance.mean()
        np_haus[number] = surface_distance.max()

        np_diam_GT[number] = diam_vol[0]
        np_diam_pred[number] = diam_vol[1]
        np_diam_err[number] = diam_vol[2]

        np_vol_GT[number] = diam_vol[3]
        np_vol_pred[number] = diam_vol[4]
        np_vol_err[number] = diam_vol[5]

    mean_dice = np.mean(np_dice)
    mean_jacq = np.mean(np_jacq)
    mean_sens = np.mean(np_sens)
    mean_spec = np.mean(np_spec)
    mean_surf = np.mean(np_surf)
    mean_haus = np.mean(np_haus)
    mean_diam_GT = np.mean(np_diam_GT)
    mean_diam_pred = np.mean(np_diam_pred)
    mean_diam_err = np.mean(np_diam_err)
    mean_vol_GT = np.mean(np_vol_GT)
    mean_vol_pred = np.mean(np_vol_pred)
    mean_vol_err = np.mean(np_vol_err)

    return ([mean_dice, mean_jacq, mean_sens, mean_spec, mean_surf, mean_haus, mean_diam_GT, mean_diam_pred, mean_diam_err, mean_vol_GT, mean_vol_pred, mean_vol_err])
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please read [ask]. Tell us what this code accomplishes. By `glab()`, do you mean `glob()`? Is this real working code? What do `scoring_baby()`, `surfd()` and `diam()` do?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Hi, and thank you very much for your time. glab() is glob() with natural sorting (so I can find myself more easily in my data folder); scoring_baby() calculates the dice score, jacquard index, sensibility and specificity between a ground truth label (binary mask) and a predicted label (binary mask as well), surfd() calculates the surface distance between the two lables, and  diam() calculates the different diameter and volume of the 3D segmentation. All the code is working, I just wanted to improve and understand more how to write proper code.

Comment: It would be nice if you provide a description or link to explain *segmentation*, for those who know Python but don't have the same domain knowledge of the problem space.

Answer (score 2):

Realy, dud its childish!

only ones:

```
lenf = len(folder)
```

just one 2d array:

```
len_types = 12
arr = np.zeros([lenf ,  12])
```

learn how to work with numpy arrays, you will avoid the loop as well. And for example the mean can be done in one line for 2d array:

```
means = np.mean(arr, axis = 1)
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry I am new to this and clearly need improvement on the manipulation of matrices with numpy. Using you advice I was able to correct my code [see EDIT first post]. But I feel more can be done, do you have other suggestions ? (sorry for the noobism here)

Comment: wait a bit, i can create good numpy tutorial from this example and ll post here later

Answer (score 1):

## return lists

your functions seem to return lists or tuples. For 2 or 3 values, this is ok, but `diam` returns 6 values, `metrics` 12. This is very unclear, and unstable when you want to add, reorder or remove a metric. Better would be then to either return a `dict` or a `namedtuple`

## spacing

pep-8 recommends  around operators (`+`,...) I use  a code formatter ([black](https://github.com/python/black)) to format my code, so I don't have to worry about this sort of details any more

## variable naming

longer variable names don't make your program slower. And if you use a capable IDE, it doesn't slow the coding either. abbreviated variable names on the other hand make code more unclear. There is no need to shorten `jacquard` to `jack`

## magical values

`[0.625, 0.625, 0.625], 1` as arguments to `surface_distance` are magical values, and very unclear what they mean. Easier would be to replace them with a variable with a clear name, or use keyword arguments.

## containers

If you have a lot of metrics, it is generally cleaner to keep them in 1 data structure (`dict` for example) instead of 12 different variables, and 12 other variables for the means.

## pandas

Instead of using `numpy` directly, why not use a [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html) DataFrame as data structure? This will allow you to work with labeled data.

```
import pandas as pd


def metrics(savedir):

    """3D metrics for segmentation evaluation:

    dice score : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient
    jacquard index : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index
    sensibility & specificity : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity
    diameter and volume error
    Surface distance : https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/7732/CS-RR-15-08.pdf
    Hausdorff distance : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance
    """

    folder = glab(savedir + "/OutputData/*/")
    results = pd.DataFrame(
        index=folder,
        columns=[
            "dice",
            "jacquard",
            "sensibility",
            "specificity",
            "surface",
            "hausdorff",
            "diam_GT",
            "diam_pred",
            "diam_err",
            "vol_GT",
            "vol_pred",
            "vol_err",
        ],
        dtype=float,
    )
    for folder_name in folder:
        prediction = np.load(folder_name + "prediction.npy")
        ground_truth = np.load(folder_name + "test_label.npy")

        scores = scoring(ground_truth, prediction)
        surface_distance = surfd(
            prediction, ground_truth, [0.625, 0.625, 0.625], 1
        )
        diam_vol = diam(prediction, ground_truth)
        results.loc[folder_name] = pd.Series(
            {
                "dice": scores[0],
                "jacquard": scores[1],
                "sensibility": scores[2],
                "specificity": scores[3],
                "surface": surface_distance.mean(),
                "hausdorff": surface_distance.max(),
                "diam_GT": diam_vol[0],
                "diam_pred": diam_vol[1],
                "diam_err": diam_vol[2],
                "vol_GT": diam_vol[3],
                "vol_pred": diam_vol[4],
                "vol_err": diam_vol[5],
            }
        )

    return results.mean().to_dict()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. Your solution is clean and very nice but I would try to use numpy as much as I can because I am learning and I feel like I am missing some of the basic mechanics of numpy which could help me in the future. But I'll look more into panda because I know that the dataframe class in panda can be interesting to work with.

Comment: Pandas uses numpy under the hood. For the thing you want to do, with the support of labelled data, it's way better suited then raw numpy

Comment: Noted, I look more into it. But I noticed that when I use your method I have different results that doesn't seem correct (nothing else was changed but the piece of code you provided). And I don't know why. I'll keep investigating. Thank you very much

Comment: Possibly, you need to add `axis=1` as argument to mean